# How to Unlock Mon Cala Aquarium Scene

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I know **how** to do this, by taking a Mon Calamari who isn't Admiral Akbar to the floor.

What I want to know is if this simply requires luck.

I do not get **?** bitizens who are Mon Calamari, only Akbar.  I have unlocked the species and have them living in the Death Star but I've not managed to unlock the Scene because I haven't had one request the floor the aquarium's on as their appearance is relatively rare.

Any guidance?

Comment: Has anyone got this via NOT paying the bux?  If so, is the Mon Calamari who unlocks it a regular Mon Calamari (e.g., shows up wanting to go to the Aquarium floor), or a "special character" Mon Calamari (with a "?")?  I'm actually thinking it is the former at this point - so not only do you need to have the luck that a Mon Calamari spawn for you (which happens very infrequently for me), but it has to go to the right floor too!

Comment: I can't remember ever seeing a Mon Calamari with a ? (other than Akbar), so I'm not sure that there's really an either-or here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to the menu and to the store.  See if there is a Mon Calamari who is available to unlock for 1 Bux.  If it is, spend the 1 Bux, and it will appear in the elevator within the next few minutes.

Then, you should be able to unlock.

Comment: So, other than luck, this is the only way to do it? Hmmm... not like one bux is hard to come by. :P

Comment: Other than luck.  Yes.

Comment: @Catija Did it work, then?

Comment: It may be worth moving the target level (Aquarium) temporarily to the top level before getting the Ithorian, because if you miss with the elevator, it isn't clear how to try again.  After unlocking the character, it won't appear in the store and if you miss with the elevator, you may have to wait for a long time to get another chance.

Answer (score 1):

I tried spending the 1 bux a couple weeks ago for the Mon Cal to unlock this scene. The Mon Cal appeared in the elevator, then the game immediately crashed. When I came back, the Mon Cal was gone and the option to buy him was gone. Now I'm just waiting to get lucky.  :(

Comment: Similar situation here, except I bought the Mon Cal during the Christmas event... and instead of it spawning, I got a decoration droid.  Ugh.  It has been months and I still haven't seen one.